# Usability problem with access lists for a network UI

Tags: usability, gui-design

I have a problem with an application I am working on. The idea is simple, in this application you build up a system of networks that are connected with each other. Example would be:

*You have Network A and Network B. They are connected with each other through a tunnel. Now let's say Network A has two computers(AA and AB) and Network B has two computers(BA and BB). You want block computer AA from communicating with Network B.*

My usability problem here is that I am using access lists for this. Each network has an access list that says which computer on their network that can communicate with other networks.

How it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgxON.png

Some users have failed to understand this concept and thought that if you want to block computer AA in Network A from talking to Network B that they should set up an access list on Network B which blocks.

Do you guys have any suggestions to remove this ambiguity or misunderstanding?

EDIT: Since I can't comment. The person who suggested I move the access list to B and deny it there. It still does not solve my problem. Some users still use the function correctly and create an access list at Network A.

Comment: So if there was a third network, C, and you wanted AA to be granted access to it, would you mark "AA Deny To B" in the A Access List?  I am confused how your diagram functions for more than 2 networks.

Comment: Actually I forgot to add. You add tunnels between networks and you configure the tunnels to use access lists. So if Network A had a connection to Network C they would have an entire setup of their own just like the picture with their own access lists.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:
[image: Network Access]

In your figure it's pretty confusing because you could think the computer from network A isn't allowed to communicate with it's own network.

putting computer AA to network B with denied permission is a more clearly way to recognize what going on, since the heading "Access list" is an universal term.